# How can I timeout a websocket after 10 seconds using websocket package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

```
        post_data = request.get_json()
        games = post_data["Games"]
        return_data = []
        print(len(games))

        def on_message(ws, message):
            return_data.append(json.loads(message))
            global received_msgs
            received_msgs += 1
            if received_msgs == len(games):
                print("found all games")
                ws.close()

        def on_error(ws, error):
            print(error)

        def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
            pass

        def on_open(ws):
            print("opened")
            global received_msgs
            received_msgs = 0
            ws.send('{"request":{"application":"games"}}')
            js = {"SubscriptionRequest": {"subscribe": {"ids": games}}}
            ws.send(json.dumps(js))

        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://localhost:4837",
                                    on_open=on_open,
                                    on_message=on_message,
                                    on_error=on_error,
                                    on_close=on_close
                                    )
        ws.run_forever()
        ws.close()
        return return_data
```

I have this block of code I use to get data from a websocket.  I wait until I have received a message for each id I sent(`games` is an array of ids).  However, this doesn't always work as expected.  Sometimes I have a single game left that hangs forever, among other possibilities. I would like to add a failsafe, where after 10 seconds, my websocket closes, and I return whatever data I have found so far. I am not sure how to accomplish this, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: websocket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout_in_seconds) call that before the construction of the ws (WebSocketApp) object.  info found here: https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#setting-timeout-value